# Zend Framework and LoginController with LoginForm

Tags: zend-framework, forms, controller

I've got some stuff I'm trying to do with ZF; I have a `LoginController.php` in `application/controllers/` with `class LoginController extends Zend_Controller_Action`.  Within it, I have the following:

```
public function getForm()
{
    return new LoginForm(array(
                'action' => '/login/process',
                'method' => 'post',
                ));
}
```

I have a `LoginForm.php` inside `application/forms/` that has the following:

```
class LoginForm extends Zend_Form
{
+-- 38 lines: public function init()--------------------------------------------
}
```

Now, when I visit example.com/login, I get the following:

`Fatal error: Class 'LoginForm' not found in /var/application/controllers/LoginController.php on line 7`

My `application.ini` is the default...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your bootstrap.php file. If you are using the standard autoloader in there, you will need to prefix your form classes with `Form_`

A basic autoloader declaration should look like something this:

```
$autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'namespace' => '',
        'basePath'  => dirname(__FILE__),
));
```

So if this is the case, your form class should be named `Form_LoginForm()`

Comment: I'm using the default project from a zf.sh create project <project>, so if that doesn't include an autoloader, then I don't either...

Where should this go?

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually create a `LoginForm` class? Because it if you did it isnt on your include path.

Answer (score 0):

name LoginForm path_from_closest_include_path_LoginForm
Assuming you have there the file LoginForm.php (notice the capital letters).

Comment: And if my include_path looks like:

`string(107) "/var/application/../library:/var/library:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear"`?

Comment: assuming the /var/application/forms/ is the dir, then forms_LoginForm

Comment: I adjusted LoginForm.php to the following:

`class forms_LoginForm extends Zend_Form`, and changed the code to call forms_LoginForm.  I still get the same error :(

Comment: when I am reading it again, I think you are not using an autoloader, or you haven't set it up correctly.

Comment: I'm using the default project from a `zf.sh create project <project>`, so if that doesn't include an autoloader, then I don't either...